# Query records from table where attribute = items from array from previous query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

table1:
id (autoincrement)
username
category

table2:
id (autoincrement)
itemname
category

I have 2 queries.

1 query one shows categories that a user (logged in) belongs to:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE '$login_session' = username";
```

I can list each record:

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "category: " . $row["category"]. "<br>";
 }
```

That works fine.

My 2nd query is dependent on the 1st query. I need to list all records from table2 where category belongs to in array category in previous query.

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE category = I DO NOT KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE";
```

How do I write $sql2?

Comment: you forgot while closing bracket `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method uses `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM table1 WHERE '$login_session' = username");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IN()

```
$sql =  'SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE category IN ('"' . implode('","', $arrayOfCategories).'"')'
```